# std::thread in Android NDK gets stuck spuriosly

Tags: android, c++, c++11, stdthread

We are building a Java/native library that has networking and video image processing in native (written mostly using c++11) and developer interface in Java.

The problem is that the whole thing gets stuck very often during jni calls.
We use latest ndk-r8e and have multiple threads running in native, created using std::thread.

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Nobody is really able to assist due to lack of detail and code. Any answers will be speculative. Provide more detail, such as the native code that is invoked plus definitions of any objects used within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end we used boost::thread instead of std::thread and that solved our problems.
I guess NDK r8e has really bad C++11 support.